# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_33

Tags: java, maven, lucene, jvm, jython

I'm getting this error when trying to use Datomic (http://www.datomic.com) from Jython:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_33
```

I used the Shade Maven plugin to create a Datomic uber jar, and I see that Lucene 3.3.0 was added:

```
Including org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.3.0 in the shaded jar
```

The uber jar is in my CLASSPATH, otherwise, it would be throwing a Datomic error.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other lucene-core JAR on the classpath?

Comment: Yep, Neo4j uses Lucene and it was on the classpath too -- removing it fixed it. Thanks Adrien.